# Superclass and passing values

Tags: java, constructor, superclass

So I have the following code

```
public class Car {
    int trunkCapacity;

    public Car (String manufacturer, int topSpeed, int trunkCapacity) {
        super();
        this.trunkCapacity = trunkCapacity;
        System.out.println("Returning from Car constructor");
    }

    public Car () {
        this("UnknownCar", 100, 1);
        System.out.println("Returning from default Car constructor");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "This trunk capacity is" + this.trunkCapacity;
    }

}
```

It keeps saying "The constructor Object(String, int) is undefined" when I put super(manufacturer, topSpeed);

I need to pass the String value and the int topSpeed into superclass, but I am not sure what to do. How would I type this super()?

Thank you all for the help, you did help improve it, but I found that the main problem was in another class I had, thank you.

Comment: What superclass? Why?

Comment: what do you think super does and super class is ?

Comment: There is supposed to be someway of doing it, the exact wording for this step is "Explicitly call super(String, int) passing values into super class" and I've only started self-teaching myself.

Comment: To call a super explicitly you first need to create an appropriate parent/super class of the child class. Then you need to tell the compiler the relationship between the two classes using the `extends` keyword. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling super?

```
public class Car
```

From the above line it is evident that you are not extending any class, which means by default Car  extends `Object` and `Object` class does not have a constructor of form `Object(String, int)`

`Object` class only one constructor of the form

[public Object ()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#Object%28%29)

[Super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)() is used to call the constructor of your super class. You can read about the constructor chaining in [here](http://java67.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-constructor-chaining-works-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

Your class `Car` does not extend any super-class, so you can't call a superclass' constructor with parameters.

Actually, your class extends the default class `Object` (the super-class for every class), so literally what you have is:

```
public class Car extends Object {
    //...
}
```

But the class `Object` has a default constructor, therefore, does not take any parameters.

If you are wishing to call a super-class, and pass the parameters to it, you must create it, and `extend` your `Car` class with it.

***Example:***

```
public class Vehicle {
    public Vehicle(String manufacturer, int topSpeed) {
        //...
    }
}
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    //...
}
```

To learn more about class (and interface) inheritance in java, Please rid this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: There is supposed to be someway of doing it, the exact wording for this step is "Explicitly call super(String, int) passing values into super class"

Comment: `Object` *does* have a default constructor.